# Overwrite exports in child containers in MEF

Tags: c#, containers, mef

We are using MEF for dependency injection in a large WPF application. In the MEF container we have registered a shared instance (**MyPriceProvider**) which provides some data to be used in some calculations.

I want to parallelize these calculations, but each calculation is altering the data inside **MyPriceProvider**. So it is important that each thread running the calculations gets its own instance of **MyPriceProvider**.

I create a child container for each thread and overwrite **MyPriceProvider** with a new instance in each child container.

However, when I resolve **MyCalculator** from the child container, it is created with a reference to the shared instance of **MyPriceProvider** from the root container.

Given these two classes **MyCalculator** and **MyPriceProvider**:

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class MyCalculator
{
    private readonly MyPriceProvider _priceProvider;

    public MyPriceProvider PriceProvider => _priceProvider;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MyCalculator(MyPriceProvider priceProvider)
    {
        _priceProvider = priceProvider;
    }
}

[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class MyPriceProvider
{

}
```

Here is a simple program reproducing the issue:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create root container:
        var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        var composablePartCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(".", "*.exe");
        aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(composablePartCatalog);

        var catalogProvider = new CatalogExportProvider(aggregateCatalog);

        var rootContainer = new CompositionContainer(catalogProvider);
        catalogProvider.SourceProvider = rootContainer;

        // Resolve shared MyPriceProvider from root:
        var priceProviderFromRoot = rootContainer.GetExportedValue<MyPriceProvider>();

        // Create child container with single ExportProvider (rootContainer)
        var childContainer = new CompositionContainer(rootContainer);

        // Overwrite MyPriceProvider in child container
        var myPriceProvider = new MyPriceProvider();
        childContainer.ComposeExportedValue(myPriceProvider);

        // Resolve MyCalculator from child Container
        var calculatorFromChildProvider = childContainer.GetExportedValue<MyCalculator>();
        if (calculatorFromChildProvider.PriceProvider ==  priceProviderFromRoot)
        {
            // PriceProvider resolved from MyCalculator is shared instance from root container, NOT the overwritten instance.
        }
    }
```

I believe I understand why **MyCalculator** gets a reference to the shared instance of **MyPriceProvider** as **MyCalculator** is registered in the root container, and when MEF is resolving its dependencies, it does not know that **MyPriceProvider** is overwritten in the child container.

I can not alter the root container in any way, because I will be creating several child containers for parallel use, and all will be sharing the same root container.

Is there any way I can configure the child container so that **MyCalculator** gets the overwritten instance when resolved from the child container?

Comment: Marking MyPriceProvider with a creation policy nonshared will not do the trick?

Comment: It would, but it has to be a singleton due to other requirements in the system.